# Get values from a dynamic checkbox list

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, ionic2

See my **html**:

```
<ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="secondary"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

My **.TS**:

```
this.database.executeSql("SELECT * FROM check_item", []).then((data) => {
        this.items = [];
        if (data.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                this.items.push({ id: data.rows.item(i).id, name: data.rows.item(i).name });
            }
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

I would like to retrieve the values from the checkbox and save it to a tablela. How can I get values from a dynamic checkbox list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index">
    <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkedItems[i]" color="secondary"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

where `checkedItems` is an array of the same size as `items` that you need to prepare and initialize.

```
checkedItems:boolean[];

constructor() { // or whereever `items` is initialized
  this.items = ...
  this.checkedItems = new Array(this.items.length);
}
```

Comment: So, now the name of my item is not showing in the list. What can it be?

Comment: Sorry, I added the `[(ngModel)]...` to the wrong line. It should be on the `<ion-checkbox>`. Are you importing `FormsModule`? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Look this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxfzFAS7MTC0SDRpdFhlcWJFanM

Comment: What about my questions from my previous comment?

Comment: Are you importing FormModule? Answer: I'm importing FormBuilder. 

Do you get an error message? Answer: I'm testing directly on the device and no error appears, but with its change, it stopped displaying the name.

Comment: Ok, if you're using `FormBuilder` you need a different approach. Instead of `[(ngModel)]...` you need to assign the value in the code where you build the control array. I would need to see the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136037/discussion-between-ack-lay-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I had the tab still open but didn't have time yet to re-visit. Glad to hear you could make it work.