# Checkbox not working. Angular 2

Tags: angular

In Oracle database there is such parameter **"active"** with data type **"VARCHAR2 (1 byte)"**. The values ​​of **Y** and **N** are used there.
I want to make the **checkbox** active if **Y** is on and not active **N**.

I wanted to do so but checkbox everywhere is active:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th [class.active]="key === 'name'" (click)="setOrder('name')"><b>Name <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></b></th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" [class.active]="key === 'active'" (click)="setOrder('active')"><b>File <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span> </b></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let project of projects | orderBy: key:reverse | let projectIndex = index" >
      <td >{{project.name}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="project.active == 'Y'" class="material_checkbox" [(ngModel)]="project.active" name="active_{{projectIndex}}"  disabled />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I set a condition so that if there was a **Y** then the **checkbox** is active and if **N** then inactive?

Comment: Use value property as well `value="{{project.active}}"`

Comment: @Sanoj_V I used, but no changes not

Comment: In your case you need use **boolean** value instead of **Y** and **N**. Because when i uncheck one checkbox it returns false value here is example: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mx9v6p) you can see here.

Comment: Here is another example : (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44135418/9775003) even i am using boolean value for multiple checkbox in `ngFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is your basic project type:

```
interface Project {
  name: string,
  active: string;

  // additional properties.
}
```

If yes, then:

```
 projectList: Project[];

  constructor() {
    this.populateProjectList();
  }

  populateProjectList(): void {
    this.projectList = [];
    this.projectList.push({name: 'project1', active: 'Y'});
    this.projectList.push({name: 'project2', active: 'N'});
    this.projectList.push({name: 'project3', active: 'Y'});
    this.projectList.push({name: 'project4', active: 'N'});
  }

// In your HTML

<p *ngFor="let project of projectList">
  <label for="">{{project.name}}</label>
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="project.active == 'Y'"> 
</p>
```

[You can play here for more options.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otrjdj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I checked, As your [ngModel] is not boolean, you should remove it. Just use like below solution:-

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="project.active == 'Y'" class="material_checkbox"  name="active_{{projectIndex}}"  disabled />
```

Comment: It did not work, all the same, all checkboxes are active

Comment: All checkbox means? Do you have other checkboxes also?

Comment: there "name" property should not be the same

Comment: You mean the checkboxes of another table?

Comment: I mean if two check boxes have same "name" property then they will behave the same. "name" property of all checkboxes should be different from each other.

Comment: No, but my flags are created by condition *ngFor="let project of projects"

Comment: You can differentiate the "name" property using this approach. Check my updated answer !!!

Comment: All the checkboxes are active it's useless (

Comment: Can you post your all checkbox code with *ngFor? Just update you question.

Comment: Also, in your question, why are you missing one " in class attribute. lolzz :)

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. I updated the question.