# How to set Checkbox FormControl for Multiple array control

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-forms, form-control

I am trying toggle/check according specific permissions with array set id's - to set permissions for users according to their user role. for an example an admin would have permissions to create users, delete, and update. My struggle with the code i've posted below is that it toggles all permissions instead of ones passed into formControl im not sure if im doing right.[image]
[image]
[image]

```js
public userList: Array < User > ;
public principalList: Array < Principal > ;
public permissionList: Array < PermissionItem > ;
public groupPermissionList: Array < PermissionGroup > ;
public permIdArr: Array < number > = [];
public permGrpIdArr: Array < number > = [];
public isSelected = false;

public updatePermsList(ev, id: number) {
  console.log(ev.target.checked, id);
  if (ev.target.checked) {
    this.permIdArr.push(id);
    console.log(this.permIdArr);
  } else {
    this.permIdArr = this.permIdArr.filter(pId => {
      return pId !== id;
    });
  }
}

public updateGrpPermsList(event, id: number) {
  if (id === 1) {
    let grpid;
    this.groupPermissionList.map(i => {
      const per = i.permissions;
      per.forEach(e => {
        grpid = e.id;
        this.permGrpIdArr.push(grpid);
      });
    });
  } else if (id === 2) {
    console.log('2nd');
  } else {
    console.log('3rd');
  }
  this.createNewUserForm.controls['app_user_permissions'].setValue(this.permGrpIdArr);
}
```

```html
<div class="user-new-container p24">
  <div [class.updating]="submitting">
    <form [formGroup]="createNewUserForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(createNewUserForm.value)" class="updater">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div *ngIf="groupPermissionList" class="row perms">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

              <h3 class="mb24">Group Permissions</h3>

              <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor="let p of groupPermissionList;let i = index" class="col-lg-4">

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 toggle-switch">
                      <input (click)="updateGrpPermsList($event, p.id)" value="p.id" type="checkbox" id="permGrp_{{i}}">
                      <label for="permGrp_{{i}}">{{p.name}}</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <br>

          <div *ngIf="permissionList" class="row perms">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

              <h3 class="mb24">Permissions</h3>

              <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor="let p of permissionList;let idx = index" class="col-lg-4">

                  <div class="form-group row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 toggle-switch">
                      <input (change)="updatePermsList($event, p.id)" formControlName="app_user_permissions" type="checkbox" [checked]="val" id="perm_{{idx}}">
                      <label for="perm_{{idx}}">{{p.name}}</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To help us better help you, could you narrow down the displayed code to the key parts (remove anything unimportant for demonstrating your issue)? Or build a stackblitz that we can use to see the issue (again limited to only the code needed to show the problem). Thanks!

Comment: i've edited the code to the most key parts